# Name and ID with formula

Tags: excel-formula, right-to-left

I have a in A column a set of values with Name and Id

1. like in cell A2 it will be --- 1100768_Sakhawat_Akram, 1100768_Sakhawat_Akram
2. like in cell A3 it will be ---  1134260_Malik, 1134260_Malik
3. like in cell A4 it will be ---  1759519, Hajraf_N_Aloteibi
4. like in cell A5 it will be ---  Hamad_Osman, 1128046

i did tried with left, right, mid, find and search function but nothing is working

1. as result in cell b2 will be 1100768 and in c2 will be Sakhawat
2. as result in cell b3 will be 1134260 and in c3 will be Malik
3. as result in cell b4 will be 1759519 and in c4 will be Hajraf
4. as result in cell b5 will be 1128046 and in c5 will be Hamad

in column B emp Id and Column C emp name

not sure as which function to use

Answer (score 0):

In B2, formula copied down :

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--MID(A2,ROW($1:$250),7),1)
```

In C2, formula copied down :

```
 =LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ","_"),B2&"_",""),FIND("_",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ","_"),B2&"_",""))-1)
```

Comment: ok, in cell B2, all is perfect, but in cell c2 in same cases Name is not displaced emp Id is displayed